# Jenkins and Copy Artifact plugin: Overwrite existing file in target project?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-plugins

I'm using Copy Artifact Plugin as a build step to copy artifacts (*.dll) from a previously build project to the lib folder of the project I'm building. However, these files normally already exists in the code repository, but I want to overwrite them with the Copy Artifact build step. Is this possible or should I add another build step to delete the existing files first?

Comment: You can let them be overwritten, but it would have been faster to just try this.

Comment: Is this the default behaviour or do I have to change anything? Because in our case, the artifacts are not overwritten.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the Copy Artifact Plugin copies files into my SCM checked-out area okay BUT I can see there is a failure to handle files if write permissions are not set.

**1. Check jenkins job console log.** Do you see the Copy message?
    See below example of message from Copy Artifact successful and fail case.

**2. Build Step Order**: Make sure the 'Copy artifacts from another Project' build step is done **after** SCM update and **before** your main build step. (obvious I know but just in case).

**3. Debug permissions and file existence** by adding build steps (or adding to execute script) directory listings of your copied in area. 'ls -alstr <dir>'

What SCM are you using? How are you checking it out?
I would guess the problem is due to write permissions on files or directory after checkout. Or possibly build step order.

ref: [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)

Successful message in console log:

```
Copied &lt;num> artifacts from "&lt;jobname>" build number &lt;jobnum>.
```

Unsuccessful message (permissions chmod 000 file) in console log:

```
FATAL: Failed to copy /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobname/builds/178/archive/file to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobname/workspace/dir/file
hudson.util.IOException2: Failed to copy /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobname/builds/178/archive/file to         /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobname/workspace/dir/file
 at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.FingerprintingCopyMethod.copyOne(FingerprintingCopyMethod.java:118)
 at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.FingerprintingCopyMethod.copyAll(FingerprintingCopyMethod.java:67)
 at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact.perform(CopyArtifact.java:526)
 at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.CopyArtifact.perform(CopyArtifact.java:460)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:78)
 at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
 at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
 at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/jobname/workspace/dir/file (Permission denied)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
 at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
 at hudson.FilePath.write(FilePath.java:1907)
 at hudson.plugins.copyartifact.FingerprintingCopyMethod.copyOne(FingerprintingCopyMethod.java:82)
 ... 13 more
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible or should I add another build step to delete the existing files first?

No you don't need to delete it explicitly and then copy, it will overwrite the existing files if you config is correct. @gaoithe's answer provides great explanation of how to debug it, if all of your building message looks good but your target files are not replaced, I'm suspicious of that you configured your `target directory` incorrectly when that artifacts is archieved from a subdirectry.

Here's an example:

- I rewrite the content of file `docker-entrypoint.sh` under subdirectory `base-image/redis/ with`git shortlog HEAD` and then archive it:

[image: config of archiving job]

- **Wrong target directory config**: I copy the artifacts in another job but specify the **target directory** to `base-image/redis/`:

[image: config with wrong target directory]

The output of `cat base-images/redis/docker-entrypoint.sh` will remain unchanged, because actually the plugin trying to do is to copy the target artifacts with its full-path to the target directory and it's supposed to be: `base-image/redis/base-image/redis/docker-entrypoint.sh`

- **Correct target directory config**: the target directory should be current directory `./`:

[image: Correct target directory config]

And then I can get what I expected.